Why does a larger diameter optical fiber reduce the resolution of a spectrometer
I am working in an experiment in optics, measuring transmittance. Light is shone on a sample, collected by an integrating sphere, the output of which is coupled to a spectrometer through an optical fiber. My professor stated that if the signal is high enough, it is best to use the smallest diameter of optical fiber possible, because it maximizes the spatial resolution of the spectrometer.
Can anyone explain why is this the case?
Thank you.

Consider how the resolution of the spectrometer changes with the angular spread of the beam at the entrance to the spectrometer.
